# Ubuntu Touch stuck at google screen

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, data-recovery, nexus-4

I tried installing Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 4. 
When I try to boot, it's stuck at the google screen.
Any ideea how to solve this? I mean booting to ubuntu, I know how to get back to recovery.

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/362607/ubuntu-touch-boot-problem

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when I forgot to flash the "saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip"
it's the one file that doesn't belong to a specific device

What I had done, to make it work:

- Installed USB drivers for the phone (make sure that you can use adb in recovery mode)
- execute: fastboot oem unlock
- restart phone into fastboot
- execute: fastboot flash recovery <...recovery....+[DEVICE NAME].img>
- execute: fastboot flash boot <...boot....+[DEVICE NAME].img>
- execute: fastboot flash system <...system....+[DEVICE NAME].img>
- go to recovery
- adb push <...touch....+[DEVICE NAME].zip> /sdcard/autodeploy.zip
- restart device to recovery, so it will apply the zip device might restart - if it does, go again to recovery
- adb push  <...touch....-armhf.zip> /sdcard/autodeploy.zip
- restart device to recovery, so it will apply the zip

Ubuntu touch loaded after this. Note that there is no splash screen, and while it loads, my screen was dark. just wait a minute.

Comment: I used the 'Manual Download & Installation' from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install). I had the same symptom when I forgot to push the last file mentioned there (saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip). Re-did it according to the instructions and everything worked.